# Как сделать плейсхолдер в QLineEdit PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qlineedit

Можно ли в проекте *PyQt5* в *LineEdit* вставить плейсхолдер, изображенный на фото, чтобы в самом поле ввода было написано, что туда вводить, но при вводе этот текст пропадал?

[image: "Найдите в Google или введите адрес"]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, можно ли сделать, как это сделано в редакторе текста поисковика, что в самом поле ввода было написано что туда вводить, но при вводе этот текст пропадал

Comment: Можно. Называется это плейсхолдером и делается с помщью метода ```.setPlaceholderText('Текст плейсхолдера')```

Comment: Спасибо, решение уже нашёл

Comment: Mr.123, вы спросили, вам ответили. То что уже нашли, вам уже давно предложили в ответах. Вам нужно выбрать ответ, который вам больше подходит и отметите его как правильный, а не публиковать свой ответ, который ничего нового не добавляет к уже данным ответам. Если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Называется это плейсхолдером и делается с помщью метода `.setPlaceholderText('Текст плейсхолдера')`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
search_entry = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(main_window)
search_entry.setPlaceholderText('Найдите в Google')
search_entry.setToolTip('Найдите в Google или введите адрес')
search_entry.setStyleSheet("""QToolTip { 
                           background-color: black; 
                           color: white; 
                           border: black solid 1px
                           }""")
search_entry.show()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line_edit = QLineEdit()
line_edit.setToolTip("Подсказка видна 3 секунды")
line_edit.setToolTipDuration(300)
line_edit.setPlaceholderText(u'Отображаемый текст')
```